# Animating and changing views inside UITableViewCell view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-animation

Let's say I subclassed `UITableViewCell` and I have some view (e.g. `UILabel`) within.

The table **has been rendered.**
Now I would like to change/animate that view.

```
|                       |         |                       |
|-----------------------|         |-----------------------|
|      label alpha=1.0  | animate |      label alpha=0.5  | 
|-----------------------|  ===>   |-----------------------|
|      label alpha=1.0  |         |      label alpha=0.5  |
|-----------------------|         |-----------------------|
|                       |         |                       |
```

So `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `willDisplayCell`, `didEndDisplayingCell` are not good options now, I think.

I created a method `animateTest` inside subclassed `UITableViewCell` which changes the style of the label - e.g. color or performs some animation.

Now in view controller which renders the table I tried to perform fast enumaration on tableview subviews.
Thanks to enumeration I caught all subclassed `UITableViewCell` instances and used `performSelector` which fires the `animateTest` method.
But nothing changes. Even if do `[tableview reloadData]`.

**How can I animate something in table cell after the table is rendered?
(using `[UIView animateWithDuration.........]`) ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should precise a bit your question : are you asking how to access a cell ? Where to call *animateWithDuration* ? I'm not really sure of your question..

Comment: Sorry, I managed to access a cell successfully (thanks to enumeration) but nothing changes... - so the second one: Where to call animateWithDuration?

Comment: It depends on what triggers the animation. Is it a button clic, a clic on the cell, etc. ?

Comment: It should be possible to fire it globally (e.g. by posting NSNotification which will perfor view controller method [that view controller is the parent of the UITableView which holds these cells])

Comment: If nothing happens, you should first try calling it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and make sure your animateWithDuration works fine (just a quick way to avoid useless painfull work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually nothing was happening because of wrong cell initialization.

I previously initialized cell in following way:

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", [indexPath section]];

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
NSArray *topLevelObjects;
topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
        {
            cell = (CustomCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Now I initialize the cell in that way:

```
static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

And everything is working fine using:

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:3]];
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
    cell.element.alpha = 0;
}];
```

If anyone can explain simply what was wrong with the first way, I will be grateful.
I suspect that cells were reset in some kind of way with that initialization so my changes were not visible because old cell (with animation applied) was thrown away and the cell was generated again.

I copied the snippet from some website some time ago so I got used to use it but apparently it's not a good implementation.